# Как правильно разработать архитектуру приложения

Tags: c#, wpf, propertygrid, wpf-toolkit

Добрый день!

Не могу понять, как лучше поступить с архитектурой, а быдлокод не хочется делать.

Есть класс значения полей которого будет редактироваться через визуальный компонент PropertyGrid.

Скажем класс выглядит так:

```
public myClass
{
    public Field Field1{get;set;}
    public Field Field2 {get;set;}
}

public Field 
{
    public int id{get;set;}
    public string value{get;set;}
}
```

В качестве значений Field будет использоваться список. Предполагаю, что он будет расположен в DataSet.Tables["Fields1"] и DataSet.Tables["Fields2"], которые будут заполняться в момент старта программы из соответствующих xml файлов, но не суть в этом.

Сам редактор, как я говорил, это propertygrid, который получает объект myClass.

Чтобы можно было редактировать, классически каждому полю myClass.Field1 и 2 соответственно назначаются атрибуты [Editor(FieldEditor, ITypeEditor)].

Так вот загвоздка у меня в чем: Разницы для редактора никакой нет, все они из себя представляют списки с выбором, однако наполнение списков разное. Не хочется плодить кучу редакторов, которые будут загружать данные соответственно из нужных файлов или таблиц. Как бы передать этим редакторам этот список возможных значений или ссылки на таблицы из которых требуется отобразить варианты выбора.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете задать свой [`TypeConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) через одноименный [атрибут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverterattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) - а у него уже можно перегрузить методы `GetStandardValuesSupported(...)` и `GetStandartValues(...)`. Это приведет к тому, что для свойства будет выбран стандартный редактор перечислений.

Если его возможностей будет не хватать - можно переопределить для типа [`TypeDescriptionProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptionprovider(v=vs.110).aspx), там вернуть свой [`PropertyDescriptor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor(v=vs.110).aspx) - а нем уже реализовать метод `GetEditor(...)` с произвольной логикой внутри.

---

Альтернативный вариант - уже в самом редакторе, в методе `ResolveEditor`, можно посмотреть `propertyItem.PropertyDescriptor` чтобы принять решение о возможных значениях.

Comment: Но ведь типы данных у класса Field1 и 2 одинаковые. Если бы нужно было из string в field преобразовать или из true сделать false, еще понимаю. А здесь мне кажется он не уместен.

Comment: Как вообще организуется модель визуальная и данные через атрибуты? У меня только на уме один вариант, что атрибутами будет указано, откуда грузить данные, а Editor будет их собирать и отображать. Только из него я не смог добраться до property, которое в данный момент редактируется.

Comment: @pincher1519 вы можете указать TypeConverter не только для типа - но и для свойства

Comment: @pavelmayorow, но ведь конвертер не позволяет производить наследование от него. Как мне тогда эти списки данных передать ему? Получается та же проблема. Мне никак не передать редактору список данных.

Comment: @pincher1519 как это - не позволяет? Что-то вы путаете...

Comment: вроде не путаю https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverterattribute(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @pincher1519 от атрибута не надо наследоваться. А наследоваться надо от TypeConverter, тип наследника указывается атрибутом.

Comment: Получается, что редактор будет один, а конвертеров столько, сколько списков требуется предоставить для выбора? А это нормальная практика?

Comment: @pincher1519 да